# Lists of games - good and bad

Tags: discussion, on-topic, subjective

This site has a lot of lists of games.  Previously these may all have been closed or converted to CW (Community Wiki).  This community appears to have chosen to allow many of these questions and find value in them.  I think only two such questions have been closed so far.

- https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/548/best-board-games-of-2010-closed
- https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/830/which-absolutely-non-mainstream-strategy-board-games-should-i-try-closed

There have been a few requests to convert other list type questions to Community Wiki.  Until recently, that wasn't an option as there were no moderators.  Now that we have moderators, how should these be handled?

My opinion is that we should hew a little closer to the guidelines set out by this blog post, http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Personally I like questions that ask for game recommendations with a good set of requirements, such as

- [Recommendations for 6-player board game](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/276/recommendations-for-6-player-board-game)
- [What cooperative board games are there that I could safely play with my wife?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/9/what-cooperative-board-games-are-there-that-i-could-safely-play-with-my-wife)

Other questions that appear just to be asking for lists I believe could be closed.

- https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1266/what-older-games-show-a-lack-of-political-correctness-today
- https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1203/are-there-board-games-about-star-wars
- [Which Settlers of Catan expansions are recommended?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1204/which-settlers-of-catan-expansions-are-recommended)

Some questions are way too subjective for my tastes
 - https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1283/what-humorous-games-are-actually-fun-for-hardcore-gamers

In closing, I'd like to see how many folks agree with my basic point that we have a few too many of these list questions.  Ideally the community would discuss some of these on meta, and close them.  I will also likely close a couple on my own.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: *Poke* - Pat, can you expand on why you locked the political correctness question?

Comment: @Jon - I deleted an answer just before leaving work.  When I got home and checked on it, the answer was undeleted.  I locked it down to ensure that only a moderator could change it again.

Comment: but if community consensus votes to re-open (or indeed close) it, shouldn't it be left as such?

Comment: @Jon - In general yes.  In this particular case, I disagree.

Answer (score 3):

Out of the three questions you link to as "just asking for lists" I think two are reasonable questions.

Asking about older games that show a lack of political correctness may be useful research for someone looking into culture change.  Asking about games that model Star Wars sounds to me like a sensible question - I don't think it's subjective.

I do agree that asking for recommendations for Catan expansions, without giving any additional requirements, is not a great question.

On a related note - if a question is closed by common consent then that's fair enough, but it seems odd to have locked it (see the [political correctness question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1266/what-older-games-show-a-lack-of-political-correctness-today-closed)).  There's no evidence of an argument and there isn't a reason given for it being locked.

Comment: +1 for arguing against the political correctness question lock. I thought that was an interesting historical thread and would vote to re-open if i could ....

Answer (score 2):

I've already voted to close on a few of the very subjective ones.  I definitely think we should go with the Guidelines for Great Subjective Questions that you link to.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to err on the side of common consensus (it's a community site after all) but most importantly avoid becoming the [Community Wiki Police](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/should-the-community-wiki-police-be-shut-down) ....