# Are questions asking what expansions are available accepted?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I've been looking to find a list of expansions for the DC Deck Building Game, but it's proving difficult.  My assumption was that board game retailers would have "Expansions" as a section on the base game's entry, but the ones I looked at did not.  The closest I've gotten is [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/boardgames/comments/81csme/dc_deck_building_game_anyone_have_a_full_list_of/) dated March 2018 with a note reading:

> This thread is archived.
>   New comments cannot be posted and votes cannot be cast

I'm unfamiliar with the way reddit works, but to me it sounds like the list there cannot be updated (and there is at least [one expansion](https://www.cryptozoic.com/dc-deck-building-game-crisis-expansion-pack-4) not listed).

I thought about asking here, but I know SE tends to disapprove of list-style questions, which asking for all the expansions for a game would likely fall into.  The closest meta I found was [this](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/263/5137), but it doesn't really answer my question.

Are questions asking for which expansions are available for a specific game on-topic?  Would it be better to ask where one could find such a list for a specific game?

Comment: I don't know if it's on- or off-topic, but [here's a list](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/125678/dc-comics-deck-building-game/expansions) of [presumably all] 28 expansions.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 Thank you for that.  This is exactly what I was hoping would have been in an answer.

Comment: Boardgame Geek is always a good place for information like that.